# How to install and configure Mozilla SpiderMonkey js engine in Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: server, javascript

How to install and configure Mozilla [SpiderMonkey js engine](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/spidermonkey/info) in Ubuntu Server 16.04? I want to use SpiderMonkey to run JavaScript code in my web app.

Answer (score 5):

SpiderMonkey is the code-name for the Mozilla's C++ implementation of  JavaScript. It is intended to be embedded in other applications that provide host environments for JavaScript.

---

### Ubuntu 21.04-22.04

To install SpiderMonkey in Ubuntu 21.04 and later open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install libmozjs-78-0 libmozjs-78-dev
```

To start Mozilla's SpiderMonkey engine, which can also be used as an interactive interpreter, from the terminal type:

```
js78
```

### Ubuntu 20.04-20.10

To install SpiderMonkey in Ubuntu 18.04-20.04 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install libmozjs-68-0 libmozjs-68-dev
```

To start Mozilla's SpiderMonkey engine, which can also be used as an interactive interpreter, from the terminal type:

```
js68
```

To exit from js68:

```
quit()
```

### Ubuntu 18.04-20.10

To install SpiderMonkey in Ubuntu 18.04-20.04 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install libmozjs-52-0 libmozjs-52-dev
```

To start Mozilla's SpiderMonkey engine, which can also be used as an interactive interpreter, from the terminal type:

```
js52
```

To exit from js52:

```
quit()
```

### Ubuntu 16.04-17.10

To install SpiderMonkey in Ubuntu 16.04-17.10 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install libmozjs-24-0v5 libmozjs-24-bin
```

To start Mozilla's SpiderMonkey engine, which can also be used as an interactive interpreter, from the terminal type:

```
js24
```

To exit from js24:

```
quit()
```

---

For additional information about how to execute JavaScript without a web browser see: [Executing JavaScript without a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941411/executing-javascript-without-a-browser). In particular I recommend that you run the foo.js example code at the end of rbrito's answer.

My example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/js
var animal = "dog";
var count = 2;
console.log("The", animal, "ate", count, "biscuits.");
```

Results:

```
The dog ate 2 biscuits.
```

Comment: Is **24** referring to a version, will this increase in the future?

Comment: Yes, it's referring to Firefox 24 and later. I don't know if Mozilla plans to update the version of SpiderMonkey, but I guess the version will be updated eventually, when I don't know.

Comment: Why does it stop at 52?

Comment: @MinhNghĩa It doesn't stop at 52. Ubuntu 20.04 and later has libmozjs-68-0 and libmozjs-68-dev, as well as libmozjs-52-0 and libmozjs-52-dev.

Comment: @karel Figured it out :) However, I'm still confused: FF is now at 78, why is SpiderMonkey stuck at 68? Is it related to ESR2, which is 68 now?

Comment: It seems like the libmozjs package maintainers are targetting Firefox ESR versions (Firefox ESR 52 and ESR2 68).